# Как открывать txt файлы двойным кликом java (javafx) приложением?

Tags: java, windows, файлы, javafx

Имеется файл `Doubleclick.jar`, который при запуске открывает окно (javafx). В окне выводится простая строка выводящая аргументы полученные из

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Есть файл `random.txt2`, при двойном клике на нём `Windows 10` предлагает выбрать программу которой открывать файл,  но при выборе `Doubleclick.jar` выдаёт сообщение

> Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем ПК

Можно ли каким-то образом открывать файлы через **jar-файлы**?

Comment: думаю, что если вы сделаете **cmd** скрипт, то все получится

Comment: Для одного файла подходит, но мне нужно открывать любой файл *.txt2 двойным кликом.

Comment: оберните ваш **jar** в **cmd** и пропишите ассоциацию

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста как это сделать. Или ссылку на инструкцию если есть такая.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно чтение файла что-то типа, по запуску jar открывается программа в которой есть Label и этот лейбл равен прочитанному файлу

```
try(FileReader file = new FileReader(path+"random.txt2")) {
    //your file
    String txt;
    int c;  
    while( (c = file.read()) != -1) { 
        txt += (char) c; 
    } // txt=txt+c;

    Label lab= new Label(txt);
}
```

Comment: Джар файл запускается не с помощью "открыть через", а двойным кликом на иконку джара.